# Firebase Remote Config never gets activated with .await()

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I have a base Remote Config initiallizer class

```kotlin
abstract class RemoteConfig: KoinComponent {

    protected val config = get<FirebaseRemoteConfig>()
    protected val dispatchers = get<AppDispatchers>()

    protected abstract fun initValues()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(dispatchers.io).launch {
            initConfig()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initConfig() {
        config.fetchAndActivate().await().let { activated ->
            if (activated) {
                initValues()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where FirebaseRemoteConfig set as single

```kotlin
single {
    Firebase.remoteConfig.apply {
        val interval = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) 0 else 900
        setConfigSettingsAsync(
            remoteConfigSettings { minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = interval.toLong() }
        )
    }
}
```

and this part of code

```kotlin
config.fetchAndActivate().await().let { activated ->
    if (activated) {
        initValues()
    }
}
```

doesn't work - **activated** variable never equals true

but if I change this part of code to

```kotlin
config.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        initValues()
    }
}
```

it works fine

Can you help me to understand, what's wrong with my initial way?

Comment: Note that `task.isSuccessful` is not the same as (`activated`). For a more accurate comparison, you should replace `task.isSuccessful` with `task.result`, because that's the equivalent to the value of `activated` from the initial way.